# Passing an data back to first activity using onBackPressed() and onActivityResult()

Tags: android, kotlin, onactivityresult, onbackpressed

I am trying to receive the user-changed value of an `Edit Text`, and set that value to the first activities `Text View`. To do this I am employing the functions `onBackPressed()` and `onActivityResult()` as shown below. However, it apperast that no data is being sent back to the first activity when then back button is being pressed

Second Activity (sending data back):

```
class MetaDataActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val name by lazy {findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextName)}

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_meta_data)

        val food =  intent.getParcelableExtra("Food") as Food

        name.setText(food.name)
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {

        val intent = Intent()
        intent.putExtra("New Name", name.toString())
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)

        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

First activity (receiving user-changed data):

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val food1: ImageButton = findViewById(R.id.imageButtonFood1)
    val name1: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textViewName1)
    val date1: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textViewDate1)

    val pizza = Food(
            "Pizza", "www.test.com", "Italy, Tomato",
            "1/1/2018", "pizza@mail.com", 5)


    date1.text = pizza.date

    food1.setOnClickListener()
    {
        val intent = Intent(this, MetaDataActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("Food", pizza)
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
    }
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (requestCode == 1) {

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val newName = data?.getStringExtra("New Name")

            textViewName1.text = newName
        }
    }
}
```

Where I'm trying to be able to edit `textViewName1`'s value from the second activity.

I believe I my parameters for the functions are correct, just cannot determine why it is not receiving the user-changed name value?

Thankyou

Comment: Do you receive a call to `onActivityResult()`? Also it appears that you're mixing synthetic view properties with manual ones.

Comment: I think, in your second activity, you should put the block `val intent = Intent() intent.putExtra("New Name", name.toString()) setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)` to your onCreate, add `finish()` after and finally invoke `onBackPressed()` function at the end of your onCreate